# Autimatic transmission not accelerating when in drive, but does when in park

Tags: transmission, nissan, acceleration

My Nissan altima 2007 doesn't accelerate when in drive but does accelerate when in park,will changing the full gear box solve this problem.I had service the gear, change the oil but still same problem

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Engine accelerate or vehicle? Checked the linkage adjustment?

Comment: Are you trying to run the engine at high RPM while you are stopped?  If so, why?